# Django ModelForm hide field from form and use value from url

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Thanks in advance for reading this. I can't wrap my head around it and it's getting quite frustrating by now.

We have the following registration form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ('name', 'company_name')

    def clean(self):
        if is not self.cleaned_data.get('card').is_available():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Error'))
```

The `Register` model includes a `card` linked to a `Card` model. This includes `is_available()` which functionally works.

Our flow is:

- The end user selects the card which lists all registrations for it.
- They click the 'Add registration'-button which brings them to cards/{PK}/add.

The `Add registration`-button is a `generic.View`. In `post(self, request, pk)` I have the following code:

```
form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
```

But how do I pass it the contents of `Card.objects.get(pk=pk)` to it?

I tried:

```
data = request.POST.copy()
data['card'] = pk
form = RegistrationForm(data)
```

But I think because `card` is not included in `fields` it gets lost somewhere, which makes sense from a `sanitize-all-input`-point of view, but I would very much like to add the `card` dynamically, in this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

So, just use [CreateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) and study how it does things using the linked site.

There is no need to use generic.View as it's the basic of basics. You only want to implement all this logic using `generic.View` to get more familiar with the way things work or if you need some very special form handling.

The short version would be:

```
from django.views import generic
from myapp.forms import RegistrationForm

class CardCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RegistrationForm
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you are going. 

Your code would raise an error because `card` is not available in `RegistrationForm.clean()`. That's the problem I have, I need to pass the primary key from the url to `RegistrationForm`, instead of it being available in the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

ModelForm has a `save` method. The correct way to solve this is to use it with `commit=False`, that will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. Then you can alter that object before finally saving it.

This is explained [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

So this is what your code should look like:

```py
form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
form.save(commit=False)
form.card = Card.objects.get(pk=pk)
form.save_m2m()
```

`save_m2m` should be used if your model has many-to-many relationships with other models. In my case, it was a OneToOne, so I used `save()` instead.

If you use a `CreateView` instead of the generic `View`, the snippet above should go into your overridden `form_valid` method